# Communicating Between Java SE and Java EE Applications

Tags: java, sockets, http, post

I have two applications: a Java SE application and a Java EE application.  The Java EE application is being run on a GlassFish server.  I want to send data in the form of JSON from the Java SE application to the Java EE application.  I want to do this with both programs running on the same computer.  The JSON sent would basically identify the student_id, student_name, instructor_name, school_name, course_name, absent_days, tardy_days, and total_grade.  On top of this I want the Java EE application to parse the JSON that is received and send it to a java db (derby) database table called reports.  I have never done something like this before and I am confused in regard to how to go about it.  I have been trying to figure out this general problem for over a month.  Can someone please help me.
1.  First of all, would I use a socket, HTTP POST Request, or combination of the two?
2.  Where exactly in the Java EE program would I even place the code that receives the socket or POST request?

```
JSON object to be sent from the Java SE application:
{“student_id”:  “123456789”,
 “student_name: “Bart Simpson”, 
  “instructor_name”: “Professor Xavier”,
  “school_name”: “Xavier High School”,
  “course_name”: “Eng12Per1”,
  “absent_days_num”: “0”,
  “tardy_days_num”: “1”,
  “total_grade”: “92.5”}
```

Comment: Q: Where exactly in the Java EE program would I even place the code that receives the socket or POST request?  A: Create a REST servlet? Here's a good tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to accomplish what you need is by creating web services on your Java EE application (REST recommended), take a look to this article to get familiarized with REST concepts http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/11/an-introduction-to-rest.html. You'll find several tutorials to create web services with REST and GlassFish.

After to have running your web services, you'll need to adapt your Java SE application as a **client** application which will consume your web services. See this other article for that http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/simple-rest-client-in-java.html